# Convert array to collection laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an array from request like this,

```
[
      "item_asset_id" => [1, 2]
      "colour_id" => [10, 11]
      "qty" => [10, 20]
      "price" => [100, 300]
      "tax_price" => [0, 0]
      "notes" => ['Item one', item two]
]
```

How to convert array like that to collection with key value
i need result like this

```
[
  ['item_asset_id' => 1, 'colour_id' => 10, 'qty' => 10],
  ['item_asset_id' => 2, 'colour_id' => 11, 'qty' => 20],
]
```

btw i am using laravel framework, thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get each array part into separate array then set the result in result array:

```
 $values =
            [
                "item_asset_id" => [1, 2],
                "colour_id" => [10, 11],
                "qty" => [10, 20],
                "price" => [100, 300],
                "tax_price" => [0, 0],
                "notes" => ['Item one', 'item two'],
            ];

        $resultArray=[];

        for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
        {
            $tempArray=[];
            $tempArray["item_asset_id"]=$values["item_asset_id"][$i];
            $tempArray["colour_id"]=$values["colour_id"][$i];
            $tempArray["qty"]=$values["qty"][$i];
            $tempArray["price"]=$values["price"][$i];
            $tempArray["tax_price"]=$values["tax_price"][$i];
            $tempArray["notes"]=$values["notes"][$i];
            $resultArray[]=$tempArray;
        }

        dd($resultArray);
```

$`resultArray` will have the desired result.

Comment: How to use collection method ?

Comment: you mean collect? $collection=collect($resultArray);